# How to properly convert GLSL 1.2 code to GLSL 1.5

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I've been trying to update some code to be OpenGL 3.2 compliant, but I'm having trouble with my shaders. I've been reading up on the differences online, and my shaders compile, but my screen remains my glClearColor. I have a vertex and fragment shader (doing phong shading). Everything works great under OpenGL 2.1 / GLSL 1.2, the problems only arise under OpenGL 3.2 / GLSL 1.5

Here are my version 1.2 shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 120

uniform mat4 uProjMatrix;
uniform mat4 uViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;

attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec3 aNormal;

varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;

void main() {
  // Transforms
  vec4 lPosition = uModelMatrix * vec4(aPosition.x, aPosition.y, aPosition.z, 1);
  vWorldPosition = vec3(lPosition.x, lPosition.y, lPosition.z);
  gl_Position = uProjMatrix * uViewMatrix * lPosition;

  // Calculate the relative normal
  vec4 lNormal = vec4(aNormal.x, aNormal.y, aNormal.z, 0);
  lNormal = uNormalMatrix * lNormal;
  vNormal = vec3(lNormal.x, lNormal.y, lNormal.z);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 120

struct Light {
  vec3 position, color;
  float constFalloff, linearFalloff, squareFalloff;
};

struct Material {
  vec3 ambient, diffuse, specular, emission;
  float shininess;
};

uniform Light uLights[10];
uniform int uNumLights;
uniform Material uMaterial;
uniform vec3 uCameraPos;

varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;

void main() {
  vec3 lNormal = normalize(vNormal);

  vec3 finalColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  for(int i = 0; i < uNumLights; ++i) {
    // Diffuse light
    vec3 toLight = uLights[i].position - vWorldPosition;
    float lightDistance = length(toLight);
    toLight = normalize(toLight);
    float diffuseAmount = max(dot(lNormal, toLight), 0.0);

    // Specular light
    vec3 toCamera = normalize(uCameraPos - vWorldPosition);
    vec3 reflection = normalize(2.0 * dot(toLight, lNormal) * lNormal - toLight);
    float specularAmount = pow(max(dot(toCamera, reflection), 0.0), uMaterial.shininess);

    // Falloff
    float falloff = 1.0 / (uLights[i].constFalloff
                          + uLights[i].linearFalloff * lightDistance
                          + uLights[i].squareFalloff * lightDistance * lightDistance);

    finalColor += ((uMaterial.diffuse * diffuseAmount
                  + uMaterial.specular * specularAmount) * falloff
                  + uMaterial.ambient) * uLights[i].color;
  }

  finalColor += uMaterial.emission;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor.r, finalColor.g, finalColor.b, 1.0);
}
```

And my version 1.5 shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 uProjMatrix;
uniform mat4 uViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;

in vec3 aPosition;
in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 vWorldPosition;
out vec3 vNormal;

void main() {
  // Transforms
  vec4 lPosition = uModelMatrix * vec4(aPosition.x, aPosition.y, aPosition.z, 1);
  vWorldPosition = vec3(lPosition.x, lPosition.y, lPosition.z);
  gl_Position = uProjMatrix * uViewMatrix * lPosition;

  // Calculate the relative normal
  vec4 lNormal = vec4(aNormal.x, aNormal.y, aNormal.z, 0);
  lNormal = uNormalMatrix * lNormal;
  vNormal = vec3(lNormal.x, lNormal.y, lNormal.z);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 150 core

struct Light {
  vec3 position, color;
  float constFalloff, linearFalloff, squareFalloff;
};

struct Material {
  vec3 ambient, diffuse, specular, emission;
  float shininess;
};

uniform Light uLights[10];
uniform int uNumLights;
uniform Material uMaterial;
uniform vec3 uCameraPos;

in vec3 vWorldPosition;
in vec3 vNormal;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  vec3 lNormal = normalize(vNormal);

  vec3 finalColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  for(int i = 0; i < uNumLights; ++i) {
    // Diffuse light
    vec3 toLight = uLights[i].position - vWorldPosition;
    float lightDistance = length(toLight);
    toLight = normalize(toLight);
    float diffuseAmount = max(dot(lNormal, toLight), 0.0);

    // Specular light
    vec3 toCamera = normalize(uCameraPos - vWorldPosition);
    vec3 reflection = normalize(2.0 * dot(toLight, lNormal) * lNormal - toLight);
    float specularAmount = pow(max(dot(toCamera, reflection), 0.0), uMaterial.shininess);

    // Falloff
    float falloff = 1.0 / (uLights[i].constFalloff
                          + uLights[i].linearFalloff * lightDistance
                          + uLights[i].squareFalloff * lightDistance * lightDistance);

    finalColor += ((uMaterial.diffuse * diffuseAmount
                  + uMaterial.specular * specularAmount) * falloff
                  + uMaterial.ambient) * uLights[i].color;
  }

  finalColor += uMaterial.emission;

  outColor = vec4(finalColor.r, finalColor.g, finalColor.b, 1.0);
}
```

I do not get any errors from compiling / linking the 1.5 shaders, but nothing draws. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know the shaders are to blame? 3.2 core deprecates more things than simply GLSL syntax.

Comment: I'd be more interested in how you're setting your uniform variables.

Comment: I guess there's a bit more that I didn't know I didn't know. As for my uniforms, I'm just using the standard 'glUniform' calls, e.g. "glUniformMatrix4fv(transHandles.uNormalMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(normal));"